# Show that a infinite dimensional vector space must have linearly independent vectors for every positive integer

Tags: vector-spaces

Show that V is infinite dimensional vector space if and only if there is a sequence $v_1,v_2,...$ of vectors in V such that $\{v_1,v_2,...,v_n\}$ is linearly independent for every positive integer n.

Comment: What have you done on this?  Where are you having difficulty?  What are your thoughts?

Comment: What exactly is your definition of "infinite dimensional"?

Answer (score 2):

Take an arbitrary $v_1\ne 0.$ Now for $n\in \Bbb N$ suppose that $S(n)=\{v_j:j\leq n\}$ is a set of $n$ linearly independent vectors. Since $V$ is  not finite dimensional we can take  some $v_{n+1}$ that does not belong to the linear span of $S(n),$ so $S(n+1)=\{v_{n+1}\}\cup S(n)$ is a linearly independentset

Without the Axiom of Choice we obtain, by induction on $n$, that for each $n\in \Bbb N$ there exists a linearly independent set of $n$ vectors. We MUST have the Axiom of Choice (or at least a corollary of it called Dependent Choice) to justify th existence of an infinite sequence of "Takes" to get an infinite sequence $(v_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ with the desired property.

Comment: can you give me hint why we need AC to justify the existence of infinite sequence?

Comment: @MeetPatel . Advanced results in Set Theory have shown that without AC it is consistent  to have an infinite set with no countably infinite subset. From this, it is consistent to have an infinite-dimensional vector space with no countably infinite subset.

Answer (score 0):

Dimension of a vector space is defined as the number of elements in the basis, provided the basis has a finite number of elements. In such cases, the vector space is said to be finite dimensional.

Therefore, a vector space is said to be infinite dimensional if the basis of the vector space has infinitely many elements. Now, a basis should be linearly independent.

An infinite subset $S$ of a vector space $V$ is said to be linearly independent, iff every finite subset $A \subset S$ is linearly independent in $V$. This gives directly that for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\left\lbrace v_1, v_2, \cdots, v_n \right\rbrace$ is linearly independent in $V$. Here, however, each $v_i$ must belong to the basis. Otherwise, the construction of the linearly independent set would be different.

Comment: I doubt that the OP has seen a proof that every vector space has a basis.

Comment: But then, how can one talk about "dimension" without talking about basis? Is there some other way?

Comment: Well, you can define "infinite-dimensional" in an elementary course to mean that the is no finite basis.  Then you can construct a countable linearly independent set by induction.

Comment: @saulspatz: ... using the axiom of choice! I remark this because it would be a clue to the OP on how to proceed. I wonder if it's consistent with ZF that there is a infinite-dimensional vector space that doesn't have a countable linearly independent set?

Comment: @Hurkyl Right.  I meant to say that for every $n$ there is a set of $n$ independent vectors.  That doesn't use the axiom of choice, right?

Comment: @saulspatz: I'm pretty sure that's correct; without choice, by induction you can show a vector space either has has arbitrarily large, finite sets of linearly independent vectors, or that it is finite dimensional.